# How can I make 2dArray syntax work on every array in memory in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, indexing

I was wondering if there was a way to use a 1d array pointer as if it were a 2d pointer:

```
int* array = new int[6*6];
my_int = array[6*i + j];   
does_not_work = array[i][j];
```

One way to achieve this is casting the 1d array to a 2d array like so:

```
int (*arr)[6] = (int(*)[6])array;
```

The problem I have with this is that I have to specify the second dimension in the declaration of the 2d array.
I want to declare this 2d array inside a class:

```
class D2Array {
    const int DIM;
//  can't do this ~v~
    char (*array)[DIM];
public:
    D2Array(int d) : DIM(d) {
        char* aux = new char[DIM*DIM];
        array = (char(*)[DIM])aux;
    }
    ~D2Array() { delete array; } 
};
```

I know about the `T** array;` method to dynamically allocate a 2d matrix, here to learn something new.

Comment: Wrap a flat c-array (or preferably a 1D `std::vector`) in a class and overload `operator()` to index it for as many dimensions as you would like.

Comment: Wrap the math to convert a x,y pair into a flat index to a function.  In C++23 you can overload the operator[] to take multiple values, to make what you're doing look very natural.  Either way, it's easiest if a class has this as a member function, and holds your actual flat array, as Richard suggested.  Give it whatever interface suits your needs.

Comment: I think this solution is equivalent to having an array of pointers, which I was trying to avoid. @RichardCritten

Comment: Well, that's one way to achieve undefined behaviour...

Comment: @ugo_capeto No, it's a one-dimensional array (or vector) with a two-dimensional interface.

Comment: @ugo_capeto a 1D flat array is the opposite of an array of pointers ie it's single contiguous  block of data (no pointers). You can easily do the maths for 2, 3 or 4 ... etc D access to it and choose row or column major ordering for locality access depending on your processing requirements.

Comment: What is your motivation to use C style arrays in C++ code? why not use containers, say a std::vector< std::vector<int>> ? easier syntax, and safer as you don't need to deal with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of array dimensions quite arbitrarily. Just cast a pointer or a reference to something that fits your needs. In the examples below, I access one array allocated as “1-dimensional” in 6 different ways, as if it was 1-, 2-, 3-, 4-, 6-, and 12-dimensional.

However, you must always specify all the dimensions, as long as you want a continuous block of memory (as opposed to “arrays of pointers”, nested vectors or some such). You need to know what exactly the block of memory represents and how big the array dimensions (and corresponding offsets) are… There’s no way around that.

In this particular case the array has the same size in all dimensions. Different situations may be even more fun, but they are not included in the example, e.g. accessing an `int[3][4][5]` as if it was an `int[5][4][3]`. Nothing stops you from doing that, of course.

One thing to keep in mind: **Always test it under `valgrind`** and make sure no memory access errors are reported.

#### A trivial implementation with raw array casting

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace {
template <typename T>
void print(const T& t) {
  std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << t;
}
}  // namespace

int main() {
  constexpr size_t size{4096}, size_root_2{64}, size_root_3{16}, size_root_4{8},
      size_root_6{4}, size_root_12{2};

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Initialize an array.
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> array{std::make_unique<int[]>(size)};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size; ++i) array[i] = i;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 1-dimensional array:
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size; ++i) print(array[i]);
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 2-dimensional array:
  const auto& array2{
      reinterpret_cast<int(&)[size_root_2][size_root_2]>(*array.get())};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_2; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_2; ++j) print(array2[i][j]);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 3-dimensional array:
  const auto& array3{
      reinterpret_cast<int(&)[size_root_3][size_root_3][size_root_3]>(
          *array.get())};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_3; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_3; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_3; ++k) print(array3[i][j][k]);
      std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 4-dimensional array:
  const auto* array4{reinterpret_cast<
      int(&)[size_root_4][size_root_4][size_root_4][size_root_4]>(
      *array.get())};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_4; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_4; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_4; ++k) {
        for (size_t l{0}; l < size_root_4; ++l) print(array4[i][j][k][l]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
      } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 6-dimensional array:
  const auto& array6{
      reinterpret_cast<int(&)[size_root_6][size_root_6][size_root_6]
                             [size_root_6][size_root_6][size_root_6]>(
          *array.get())};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_6; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_6; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_6; ++k) {
        for (size_t l{0}; l < size_root_6; ++l) {
          for (size_t m{0}; m < size_root_6; ++m) {
            for (size_t n{0}; n < size_root_6; ++n)
              print(array6[i][j][k][l][m][n]);
            std::cout << std::endl;
          } std::cout << std::endl;
        } std::cout << std::endl;
      } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 12-dimensional array:
  const auto& array12{reinterpret_cast<
      int(&)[size_root_12][size_root_12][size_root_12][size_root_12]
            [size_root_12][size_root_12][size_root_12][size_root_12]
            [size_root_12][size_root_12][size_root_12][size_root_12]>(
      *array.get())};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_12; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_12; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_12; ++k) {
        for (size_t l{0}; l < size_root_12; ++l) {
          for (size_t m{0}; m < size_root_12; ++m) {
            for (size_t n{0}; n < size_root_12; ++n) {
              for (size_t o{0}; o < size_root_12; ++o) {
                for (size_t p{0}; p < size_root_12; ++p) {
                  for (size_t q{0}; q < size_root_12; ++q) {
                    for (size_t r{0}; r < size_root_12; ++r) {
                      for (size_t s{0}; s < size_root_12; ++s) {
                        for (size_t t{0}; t < size_root_12; ++t)
                          print(array12[i][j][k][l][m][n][o][p][q][r][s][t]);
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                      } std::cout << std::endl;
                    } std::cout << std::endl;
                  } std::cout << std::endl;
                } std::cout << std::endl;
              } std::cout << std::endl;
            } std::cout << std::endl;
          } std::cout << std::endl;
        } std::cout << std::endl;
      } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

#### A quick and dirty template harness for array casting

The `ArrayCaster` class template below takes the element type and a variadic list of dimension sizes. It provides a method `at()` to specify indices for all dimensions at once and also an `operator[]` to shave the dimensions off one by one.

(And it does a few regrettable tricks that favor brevity over universal correctness for all types; a `reinterpret_cast` is as dangerous as it gets.)

In C++23, the `operator[]` can have an arbitrary number of arguments, which will make it possible to unify `at()` and `operator[]`.

Another improvement (independent of C++23) could be to further parameterize `at()` so that it resolves an arbitrary number of dimensions (fewer than all of them) and returns the corresponding “subarray”. OTOH, the same effect can be already achieved using a sequence of `operator[]`, so there’s not much to gain.

```cpp
template <typename, size_t...>
struct ArrayCaster;

template <typename Element>
struct ArrayCaster<Element> {
  using Type = Element;
  ArrayCaster(Type &ref) : ref_{ref} {}
  Element &at() const { return ref_; }
  operator Type &() const { return ref_; }  // 0-dimensional array is an element

 private:
  Type &ref_;
};

template <typename Element, size_t Dimension, size_t... Dimensions>
struct ArrayCaster<Element, Dimension, Dimensions...> {
  using Type = typename ArrayCaster<Element, Dimensions...>::Type[Dimension];
  template <typename Reference>
  ArrayCaster(Reference &ref) : ref_{reinterpret_cast<Type &>(ref)} {}

 private:
  template <size_t>
  struct ToType {
    using Type = size_t;
  };

 public:
  Element &at(size_t head, typename ToType<Dimensions>::Type... tail) const {
    return ArrayCaster<Element, Dimensions...>{ref_[head]}.at(tail...);
  }
  ArrayCaster<Element, Dimensions...> operator[](size_t head) const {
    return {ref_[head]};
  }

 private:
  Type &ref_;
};
```

#### A slightly less trivial implementation with the casting template

An example use of the `ArrayCaster` template follows. It prints each element twice, showing how `at()` and `operator[]` work. It is structured the same way as the trivial example above.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace {
template <typename S, typename T>
void print2(const S &s, const T &t) {
  std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << s;
  std::cout << " /";
  std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << t;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Paste the ArrayCaster template harness here! (See previous section.) /////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}  // namespace

int main() {
  constexpr size_t size{4096}, size_root_2{64}, size_root_3{16}, size_root_4{8},
      size_root_6{4}, size_root_12{2};

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Initialize an array.
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> array{std::make_unique<int[]>(size)};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size; ++i) array[i] = i;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 1-dimensional array:
  const ArrayCaster<int, size> array1{*array.get()};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size; ++i) print2(array1.at(i), array[i]);
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 2-dimensional array:
  const ArrayCaster<int, size_root_2, size_root_2> array2{*array.get()};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_2; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_2; ++j)
      print2(array2.at(i, j), array2[i][j]);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 3-dimensional array:
  const ArrayCaster<int, size_root_3, size_root_3, size_root_3> array3{
      *array.get()};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_3; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_3; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_3; ++k)
        print2(array3.at(i, j, k), array3[i][j][k]);
      std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 4-dimensional array:
  const ArrayCaster<int, size_root_4, size_root_4, size_root_4, size_root_4>
      array4{*array.get()};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_4; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_4; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_4; ++k) {
        for (size_t l{0}; l < size_root_4; ++l)
          print2(array4.at(i, j, k, l), array4[i][j][k][l]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
      } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 6-dimensional array:
  const ArrayCaster<int, size_root_6, size_root_6, size_root_6, size_root_6,
                    size_root_6, size_root_6>
      array6{*array.get()};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_6; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_6; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_6; ++k) {
        for (size_t l{0}; l < size_root_6; ++l) {
          for (size_t m{0}; m < size_root_6; ++m) {
            for (size_t n{0}; n < size_root_6; ++n)
              print2(array6.at(i, j, k, l, m, n), array6[i][j][k][l][m][n]);
            std::cout << std::endl;
          } std::cout << std::endl;
        } std::cout << std::endl;
      } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Access the array as a 12-dimensional array:
  const ArrayCaster<int, size_root_12, size_root_12, size_root_12, size_root_12,
                    size_root_12, size_root_12, size_root_12, size_root_12,
                    size_root_12, size_root_12, size_root_12, size_root_12>
      array12{*array.get()};
  for (size_t i{0}; i < size_root_12; ++i) {
    for (size_t j{0}; j < size_root_12; ++j) {
      for (size_t k{0}; k < size_root_12; ++k) {
        for (size_t l{0}; l < size_root_12; ++l) {
          for (size_t m{0}; m < size_root_12; ++m) {
            for (size_t n{0}; n < size_root_12; ++n) {
              for (size_t o{0}; o < size_root_12; ++o) {
                for (size_t p{0}; p < size_root_12; ++p) {
                  for (size_t q{0}; q < size_root_12; ++q) {
                    for (size_t r{0}; r < size_root_12; ++r) {
                      for (size_t s{0}; s < size_root_12; ++s) {
                        for (size_t t{0}; t < size_root_12; ++t)
                          print2(array12.at(i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t),
                                array12[i][j][k][l][m][n][o][p][q][r][s][t]);
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                      } std::cout << std::endl;
                    } std::cout << std::endl;
                  } std::cout << std::endl;
                } std::cout << std::endl;
              } std::cout << std::endl;
            } std::cout << std::endl;
          } std::cout << std::endl;
        } std::cout << std::endl;
      } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
  } std::cout << std::endl;
}
```